# The name 'InputElement' isn't a type,

Tags: flutter, flutter-html

I am trying to make a web scrawler.when I add this line of code

document.querySelectorAll("div.search-button input[type=button]")[0] as InputElement

I am getting this error

```
Error: 'InputElement' isn't a type.
```

I have added html and http packages

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

How can i fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-html/InputElement-class.html

"dart:html library"

so

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Comment: I added this lib as you suggested but this error showed up                                           "Avoid using web-only libraries outside Flutter web plugin packages"                           then I had to add  universal_html: ^1.2.1 package also .And this time another error ...

Comment: "Because universal_html ^1.2.4 depends on html ^0.14.0 and universal_html >=1.1.21 <1.2.4 depends on html >=0.13.4 <0.15.0, universal_html ^1.1.21 requires html >=0.13.4 <0.15.0.
So, because webscarpp depends on both universal_html ^1.2.1 and html ^0.15.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because webscarpp depends on both universal_html ^1.2.1 and html ^0.15.0, version solving failed.)" I couldnt figure what should i do